# Is there a way to read Google Trends with an HTTP request?

Tags: http, rest

Is there a way to read output from Google Trends using an HTTP request?

I would like to use HTTP requests to read data from Google Trends for an app I am developing. I have some experience with REST. Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use this API [Google trend](http://hawttrends.appspot.com/api/terms/) and get all country json format data.
Country code reference:http://myweb.fcu.edu.tw/~mhsung/Research/InformationSystem/JSON/JSON_24.htm

Answer (score 0):

> An API to accompany the Google Trends service was announced by Marissa Mayer, vice president of search-products at Google. This was announced in 2007, and so far has not been released.

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Trends#Google_Trends_API)